# What is the best way to make a search for match at each item in a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, match

`using Visual.Web.Developer.2010.Express;`

N00b here,

I know there is plenty of ways to do this, but which would be the most efficient? I have 2 text areas with items that are related to eachother (`aT1`&`aT2`).. What way would be the most efficient to compare all the content in 'aT2' for each item in 'aT1'. How would I separate each item in 'aT1'? If it was to find a match, it would select that whole line where the match occurred in 'aT2'.  I did a trusty 'ol Google search, and I ran into `Regex`, `string.match`, and `List<string>`.. Is there some obvious one that I have ran over and didn't stop to check? Any help/pointers at good tutorials would be appreciated! Not really looking for code, but if you must you can post some code.

Here's a few in `aT1`:

```
ABC9910A
ABC42554
LOW3381
BD6210HFP
NWP448A1S
OTT123A04NS
```

Here's a few in `aT2`:

```
APPLEMACHINE    Y   ABC9910AIMAP
APPLEMACHINE    Y   ABC42554AIRAJZ
BANANABOI   Y   LOW33811CBZ
LLBLEAD TECHN   Y   NWP448A1S3LWXFTMA1
LLBLEAD TECHN   Y   OTT123A04NS4NSGATMA1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would store aT1 as a list of strings(by spiting on the line break character).

Loop through that list and use a regex to see if it matches anything in aT2 and you can also use that regex to select the line that it matches.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
//guessing on .Text
var matches =
    from a in at2.Text.Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 
    from b in at1.Text.Split(new [] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 
    where a.Contains(b)
    select a;
```